# Adding Selected Option Prices for Checkboxes - Using Svelte

Tags: checkbox, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm trying to get update the total as the checkboxes are selected and unselected (incase the user changes their mind and no longer wants the item). But I'm not sure how to get the actual value I have assigned to each toy. For example: If the user selects toy 1 and 3 they should see: You ordered Toy1, Toy3 and your total is $6.00. For now I assigned the values with the names themselves which isn't what I want but I just put that to show what I'm trying to do. Is their something else I should be using actually perform an operation to get the total?

```
<script>
        let toylist = [];
        let toynames = [
                     'Toy1 5.00',
           'Toy2 5.00',
                     'Toy3 1.00',
        ];

        function join(toylist) {
            return toylist.join(', ');
        }
</script>
    {#each toynames as toy}
        <label>
            <input type=checkbox bind:group={toylist} value={toy}> {toy}
        </label>
    {/each}

    {#if toylist.length === 0}
        <p>Pick at least one toy</p>
     {:else}
        <p>
           You ordered {toylist.join(', ')} and your total is
        </p>
    {/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first you should separate the toynames array into an array of names and values. Then you should bind to the checked property of the input.

In order to display the current state to the user, we need a reactive declaration. Let's call it total. It contains two functions. The first one gives back an array of the selected names, the second the sum of the selected values.

Both work by looking at the selected property of the object in the toylist array. This updates due to our binding of the checked attribute. I created a [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/6f48b99ebf904076820348c0b430222e?version=3.20.1) for you to toy ;-) around with

```
<script>
    let toylist = [
        {name: "Toy", value: 5, selected: false},
        {name: "Elephant", value: 6, selected: false}, 
        {name: "Choo-Choo", value: 1, selected: false}
    ]

  $: total = {
    names: toylist.reduce((acc, cV) => {
      if (cV && cV.selected) {
        return [...acc, cV.name];
      } else return [...acc];
    }, []),
    values: toylist.reduce((acc, cV) => {
      if (cV && cV.selected) {
        return parseInt(acc) + parseInt(cV.value);
      } else return parseInt(acc);
    }, 0)
  };

</script>
    {#each toylist as {name,value, selected}}
        <label>
            <input type=checkbox bind:checked={selected} bind:value={value}> {name}
        </label>
    {/each}

    {#if toylist.length === 0}
        <p>Pick at least one toy</p>
     {:else}
        <p>
           You ordered {total.names.length < 1 ? "nothing": total.names} and your total is {total.values}
        </p>
    {/if}
```

**EDIT:**
Here is the total function with a more *classic* syntax:

```
  $: total = {
    names: toylist.reduce(function(acc, cV) {
      if (cV && cV.selected) {
        return [...acc, cV.name];
      } else return [...acc];
    }, []),
    values: toylist.reduce(function(acc, cV) {
      if (cV && cV.selected) {
        return parseInt(acc) + parseInt(cV.value);
      } else return parseInt(acc);
    }, 0)
  };
```

And here without the ? operator:

```
<script>
  function renderNames() {
    if (total.names.length < 1) {
      return "nothing";
    } else {
      return total.names;
    }
  }
</script>

 <p>You ordered {renderNames()} and your total is {total.values}</p>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding some of the code when the ... and ? are used. Also is it possible to do this without arrow functions I'm getting confused with them. I'm also confused on what acc and cV are. Btw loved the joke haha @Gh05d

Comment: Basically a ? (tertiary operator) is a short hand for if (){} else {}. For the reduce function, you can find more information here: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/… 

acc means accumulator, so the summed up results from previous iterations and cV means current Value, so the value in the current iteration. I will update my code with basic functions.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to isolate the price of each toy would be to make your array of toys into an array of objects where 'name' is one key value pair and price another. For manipulating the data it would be helpful if each toy had an id, and I've added a 'selected' boolean value to each toy that is updated if they are added or removed from the "toylist". I've also added a 'total' variable to hold the total of selected toys prices.

I have played with your code a bit to make this work. I have used buttons instead of checkboxes but you could do it in any way you like. So give this code a go and it should be doing what you want.

```
<script>
  let toylist = [];
  let toys = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Toy 1', price: 5.00, selected: false},
        {id: 2, name: 'Toy 2', price: 5.00, selected: false},
        {id: 3, name: 'Toy 3', price: 1.00, selected: false}
    ];
  let total = 0.00
  function join(toy) {
        if(toy.selected === false) {
            toylist = [...toylist, toy.name]
            total = total+toy.price
            let i = toys.findIndex(t => t.id === toy.id)
            toys[i].selected = true
            toys = toys
        } else {
            total = total-toy.price
            let i = toys.findIndex(t => t.id === toy.id)
            let i2 = toylist.findIndex(t => t === toy.name)
            toylist.splice(i2, 1)
            toylist = toylist
            toys[i].selected = false
            toys = toys
        }
  }
</script>
{#each toys as toy}
    <label>
        {toy.name}: ${toy.price} <button on:click="{() => join(toy)}" value={toy.name}>{toy.selected ? 'remove' : 'add'}</button>
    </label>
{/each}

{#if toylist.length === 0}
    <p>Pick at least one toy</p>
{:else}
    <p>
        You ordered {toylist} and your total is ${total}
    </p>
{/if}
```

Comment: We think similar, down to the variable names :-)